# what is difference between CLBs MUX based and LUT based

Tags: fpga

as you know FPGAs have made using CLBs and some CLB are MUX based and some are LUT based,

so what is the difference between CLBs MUX based and LUT based?

how MUX based are implemented in CLBs?

Comment: *"as you know"* I'll plead ignorance. I only have encountered CLB based FPGA's. The only other programmable type I know are AND/OR structures which I would not put in the FPGA but in the PLD category. In general questions like this you should be able to solve yourself by looking up the data sheets of TYPE A and TYPE B and compare them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most modern FPGA CLBs are actually a mix of both. The basic elements are LUTs (which tend to use muxes internally, but that's another story); then you have some extra 2:1 muxes (MUXF7 and MUXF8 in Xilinx land) that can optionally be used to combine the LUTs to build more wider functions like large multiplexers.